# Order properties of object by value of customAttribute

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, reflection, linq-to-objects

What I'm trying to do is wirte linq expression which allows me to order my `List<PropertyInfo>` of some object by Custom attribute for example:

```
public class SampleClass{

   [CustomAttribute("MyAttrib1",1)]
   public string Name{ get; set; }
   [CustomAttribute("MyAttrib2",1)]
   public string Desc{get;set;}
   [CustomAttribute("MyAttrib1",2)]
   public int Price{get;set;}
}
```

CustomAttribute.cs:

```
public class CustomAttribute: Attribute{
    public string AttribName{get;set;}
    public int Index{get;set;}
    public CustomAttribute(string attribName,int index)
    {
        AttribName = attribName;
        Index = index;
    }
}
```

so far I was able to get all properties from my class named SampleClass:

```
List<PropertyInfo> propertiesList = new List<PropertyInfo>((IEnumerable<PropertyInfo>)typeof(SampleClass).GetProperties());
```

my tryed so far to sort this `propertiesList` (which btw doesn't work) :

```
var sortedPropertys = propertiesList
            .OrderByDescending(
                (x, y) => ((CustomAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute((PropertyInfo) x, typeof (CustomAttribute))).AttribName 
                .CompareTo((((CustomAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute((PropertyInfo) y, typeof (CustomAttribute))).AttribName ))
            ).OrderByDescending(
                (x,y)=>((CustomAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute((PropertyInfo) x, typeof (CustomAttribute))).Index
                .CompareTo((((CustomAttribute) Attribute.GetCustomAttribute((PropertyInfo) y, typeof (CustomAttribute))).Index)))
                .Select(x=>x);
```

**Output List should be (I'll tell it only with PropertyInfo.Name):**

```
property name: Name,Price,Desc
```

My question is: **Is it possible to do that? And If yes how can I do this properly?**

If you have some question pls ask (I'll do my best to answer every uncertainties). I hope description of problem is enough.

Thanks for advance:)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var props = typeof(SampleClass)
    .GetProperties()
    .OrderBy(p => p.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<CustomAttribute>().First().AttribName)
    .ThenBy(p => p.GetCustomAttributes().OfType<CustomAttribute>().First().Index)
    .Select(p => p.Name);

var propNames = String.Join(", ", props);
```

OUTPUT: Name, Price, Desc

Comment: I meant output `List<PropertyInfo>` in this order of property.Name :) and Yours solution doesn't work `p.GetCustomAttributes()` need argument `bool`

Comment: When I write same thing VS2010 can't figure out any method after `p.GetCustomAttributes()` because there is no parameterless method of `GetCustomAttributes()`

Comment: When I add parameter in method like this `GetCustomAttributes(false)` your answer work :) Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

I was reading this because i wanted to see for xml attributes and met errors because it seems with this answer i get also attributes i don't want. Then i made something that seems to work and i say to myself it could help somebody else someday.

```
IOrderedEnumerable<PropertyInfo> Properties = typeof(FooClass).GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.CustomAttributes.Any(y => y.AttributeType == typeof(XmlElementAttribute)))
                .OrderBy(g=> g.GetCustomAttributes(false).OfType<XmlElementAttribute>().First().Order);
```